# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException on Spring Boot Upgrade from Version 1.5 to Version 2.1

Tags: spring-boot

In my Spring Boot Application, I'm getting Error while upgrading Spring Boot from 1.5 to 2.1 version:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pushNotificationsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pushNotificationUtil'; 

nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

Error creating bean with name 'pushNotificationsUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pushNotificationFeignClient'; 

nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xyz.abd.service.PushNotificationFeignClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; 

nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
```

**I'm sharing source code below:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
EnableCircuitBreaker
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan({"com.abc.upoint","com.def.portal"})
@EnableFeignClients
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

PushNotificationsController.java:

```
@RestController
public class PushNotificationsController {

  @Autowired
  private PushNotificationsUtil pushNotificationUtil;
}
```

PushNotificationsUtil.java:

```
@Component
public class PushNotificationsUtil {

    @Autowired
    private PushNotificationFeignClient pushNotificationFeignClient;
}
```

PushNotificationFeignClient.java:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;

@FeignClient(name="channel-pushnotifications", url = "${onesignal.url:#{''}}", fallback = 
PushNotificationFeignClient.PushNotificationFallback.class
                                      , configuration=UpointFeignProxyConfiguration.class)
public interface PushNotificationFeignClient {

    class PushNotificationFallback implements PushNotificationFeignClient {
       // Method Implementations
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application or Spring MVC or Spring Core alone? please provide more information on how you're initializing your Application Context.

Comment: Yes, It is a Spring Boot Application.

Comment: Please share the entry-point class, and maybe entire `PushNotificationsUtil` class as well.

Comment: Is it neccessary to declare PushNotificationFallback as an inner class? I don't know whether it's the reason of problem but it may cause some problems. I would Try to declare `PushNotificationFallback` outside of `PushNotificationFeignClient'.